# PIG automatically connected with default HDFS, how?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I just started learning Hadoop and PIG (from last two days!) for one of my future project.

For experiments I've installed Hadoop (HDFS on default localhost:9000) as pseudo distributed mode and PIG (map-reduce mode).

When I initialized PIG by typing ./bin/pig command it launched GRUNT command line and I got message that pig connected with HDFS (localhost:9000), later I could successfully able to access HDFS thru pig.

I was expecting to perform some manual configuration for PIG to access HDFS (as per various internet articles).

My question is, from where PIG identified default HDFS configuration (localhost:9000)? I checked pig.properties but I didn't find anything there. I need this info as I might change default HDFS configuration in future.

BTW, I have HADOOP_HOME and PIG_HOME defined in my OS PATH variable.

Comment: Its very easy to find ...why don't you open pig(shell file) where can see how it is setting the paths of hadoop variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Pig (I assume v0.10.0) you have to tell how it will connect to the `HDFS`.
I don't know how you did this but *generally* this is done by adding the hadoop conf dir path to the `PIG_CLASSPATH` environment variable. You can also set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` as well.

If you are starting the grunt shell Pig will locate the directory of the Hadoop configuration XMLs, and takes the value of `fs.default.name` (core-site.xml) and `mapred.job.tracker` (mapred-site.xml) , i.e: the location of the Namenode and JobTracker.

For reference you may have a look at the Pig shell script to see how env. variables are collected and evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I use v0.10.0....my installation for PIG was download .tar and extracted it (on my Mac) - after untar I directly executed /bin/pig to get grunt prompt and I got message that "pig connected to HDFS successfully"....I never executed any Java command for PIG installation....

Comment: I was looking everywhere and not actual PIG (bin/pig) script....I got information on how PIG is using HADOOP_HOME etc while initialization (when I execute /bin/pig) - Thanks

Comment: so the salient point is, pig doesn't have its own config for the URL, it uses the one defined in hadoop/conf/core-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

PIG can connects to underlying HDFS in the 3 ways

1-
Pig uses HADOOP_HOME for finding the HADOOP client to Run.
your HADOOP_HOME should have been already setup in your bash_profile
export HADOOP_HOME=~/myHadoop/hadoop-2.5.2

2-
or else there might be possibility that your HADOOP_CONF_DIR has already been setup which contains the xml file for the hadoop configuration
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/

3-And if these are not setup you can also connect to underlying hdfs 
by changing the pig.properties which is present under PIG_HOME/conf dir